# Use ECMAScript 6 template string to construct HTTP request

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

On [this page](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/), under "Template Strings", this example is given:

```
// Construct an HTTP request prefix is used to interpret the replacements and construction
GET`http://foo.org/bar?a=${a}&b=${b}
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Credentials: ${credentials}
    { "foo": ${foo},
      "bar": ${bar}}`(myOnReadyStateChangeHandler);
```

Here's what I ***do*** understand (mostly from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)):

- The basic idea of the example is to produce an HTTP GET request.
- Items like `${foo}` in a template string will be replaced dynamically.
- A tag can be prefixed to a template string to call a function with the same name and modify the produced string.

Here's what I ***don't*** understand and would like to know:

- Is there something special about the `GET` tag in ECMAScript 6?
- What happens you attach `(myOnReadyStateChangeHandler)` to the end of a tagged template string?

Comment: In this case, it is not a string being produced, but rather a function. The tag does not "modify the produced string"; it specifies an alternative way to process the content between the backticks and returns whatever it wants, a function in this case. There is no special GET tag; it's implemented by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tagged template strings are just syntax sugar for function calls. The example you have given would expand to something like:

```
GET(['http://foo.org/bar?a=', '&b=', '\nContent-Type: application/json\nX-Credentials: ', '\n\n{ "foo":', '"bar":', '}'] a, b, credentials, foo, bar)(myOnReadyStateChangeHandler)
```